# How to delete rows in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have just begun using jqGrid, and I want to delete rows using a custom delete button. I am using the code snippet below:

```
try {
        var cellValue;
        var id;
        jQuery("#editDataGridList").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            width: 900,
            height: 270,
            colNames: ['Action', 'Interview id', 'Date of observation', 'Name of enumerator'],
            onSelectRow: function (id) {
                debugger;
                var rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(id);                   
                cellValue = rowData['InterviewId'];
            },
            colModel: [                
                 {
                     name: 'actions', index: 'InterviewId', sortable: false,
                     formatter: function (rowId, cellval, colpos, rwdat, _act) {

                         return "<input type='button' id='btnid' value='delete' class='btn' onClick='deleteRecords(" + cellValue + ");' />";

                     }
                 },
                { name: 'InterviewId', index: 'InterviewId' },
                { name: 'Date', index: 'Date' },
                { name: 'NameOfEnum', index: 'NameOfEnum' }
            ],

            multiselect: false,
            caption: "Edit already entered data"
        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
```

The above code uses this function call to pass the selected row value for deletion

```
function deleteRecords(rowData) {
    alert(rowData);
}
```

Unfortunately the rowData value is undefined.
How can I use the same structure to delete the rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to my own problem.

```
formatter: function (rowId, cellval, colpos, rwdat, _act) {
       var rowInterviewId = colpos.InterviewId.toString();
       return "<input type='button' id='" + rowInterviewId + "' value='delete' class='btn'
       onClick='deleteRecords(this)' />";    
}
```

i just pass this as a parameter to the button onclick event and on the function call this has all the properties i needed from the button but the most important one being the button id which is the interview ids of the row that the button belongs to.

Answer (score 13):

you can delete row using

```
$('#editDataGridList').jqGrid('delRowData',rowid);
```

Comment: @Waaqas...the problem is that i cannot access the rowid of the row containing the delete button using the return button html code above...but inside the onSelectRow is workable.

Comment: also "delrowdata" doesn't call the back end.

Comment: write a custom method, that does both the jobs, deletes the row from ui, and back-end using ajax.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `cellValue` is not defined in the same scope as your delete formatter is.  You could try two things:

1. Pass the `rowId` argument from your formatter to the delete function instead of `cellValue`.
2. Declare a variable outside of the scope of BOTH functions and then set that variable to the ID value of the selected row in your `onSelectRow` handler.

Comment: @AJ...funny enough is that in the formatter only the colpos parameter has value the others including rowId have no values. then when i set the variable outside of both functions and set that variable to the ID value of the selected row in my onSElectRow handler that value(rowId) wont change even if i click on different deleted buttons but it will only change upon clicking outside the delete button in any row. I think the challenge is how to connect the buttons to the cells coz when i click on a button it the grid doesnt have any info that that button is in row 1 or 2 etc...

Comment: Then you have to declare a variable outside of your jquery `ready` call, set it to the rowId in `onSelectRow`, and then retrieve it in your delete handler.

Comment: @AJ. Please share the delete function from where the row is actually remove from the grid. Actually I cant figure it out how to remove that row from the grid.